# Simple Odoo/Python/XML

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have 2 questions.
First one.

This field have to be integer greater or equal than to 50. how can i do this.

```
value = fields.Integer("Value", required=True)
```

second question.

i wanted to add search by "name" but if i run this coed i getting TypeError:Type is not constructor. what is wrong with my search section? without search section it runs normal.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="helloworld.list2">
      <field name="name">helloworld listx</field>
      <field name="model">helloworld.test2</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search>
          <field name="name"/>
        </search>
        <tree>
          <field name="name"/>
          <field name="reference"/>
        </tree>
      </field>
    </record>
```

**UPDATE.**

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
from openerp.exceptions import ValidationError


class HelloWorld(models.Model):
    _name = 'helloworld.test'
    name = fields.Char("Name", required=True, size=20)
    value = fields.Integer("Value", required=True)

    # I am adjusting the indentation below so the methods become part of your class

    @api.onchange('value')
    def _onchange_value(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.value < 20:
                raise ValidationError("Your record is too small: %s" % record.value)
```

Comment: If you find this answer helpful I would appreciate it if you would mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways it could be done however the 'constrains' decorator is probably what you want. If not you could override the 'write' and 'create' methods to raise exceptions.

The constrains functions will run before a write or creation of a record. And will not allow the record to be written unless the value passes the validation.

```
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

@api.constrains('value')
def _check_value_field(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.value < 50:
            raise ValidationError("Your record is too small: %s" % record.value)
```

With regards to your search view. You also have a tree view. The search view and tree view are separate things altogether. You should define them separately.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="helloworld.tree2">
      <field name="name">test2.tree</field>
      <field name="model">helloworld.test2</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>
          <field name="name"/>
          <field name="reference"/>
        </tree>
      </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="helloworld.search2">
      <field name="name">test2.search</field>
      <field name="model">helloworld.test2</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search>
          <field name="name"/>
        </search>
      </field>
</record>
```

You can if you wish provide immediate validation of field data using an 'onchange' function as well (as ***CZoellner*** recommended), this will immediately notify the user the entered value is invalid however should not be used for record validation as the user can simply bypass the error message. Here is an example.

```
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

@api.onchange('value')
def _onchange_value(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.value < 50:
            raise ValidationError("Your record is too small: %s" % record.value)
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way? For example if we want that our  field lenght be 20 max we do it like fields.interger(size=20) maybe there is something similar?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: Totally agree with your answer Phillip. You might want to augment it by changing the `record.value < 50` to `record.value >= 50` since the OP mentioned "greater or equal than to 50"

Comment: I think the above should work. It should only create an error if the field is below 50. Which is what he wants. I actually had the opposite at first until I took a closer look.

Comment: @PhillipStack i would also add the possibility to use an onchange event for this behaviour. Why? Because it will evaluate the input "instantly" while constrains will hint the user very late (on save or create).

Comment: On change works to provide a warning to the user. However can the user bypass this and just save the record anyway? Maybe 'constrains' and 'onchange' together might be a good idea.

Comment: i do have i problem with this. i still can save value less then 50. i tried onchange and constrains... i enter value 1 and save it and dont get any errors..

Comment: Please update with the actual code you are using. There is probably just a misunderstanding of the example. It will be straightforward once you see a working example.

Comment: The tabbing on your onchange method would be an issue. I just tried the exact code from these examples (both onchange and constrains) and they both work. You need to tab you methods so the python interpreter knows they are members of the class. I made a modification to your post with proper formatting.

Comment: ohh that was embarrassing from my part. thank you for patients.

Comment: EVERYONE especially ME, makes stupid programming errors.